# Add appcompat v7 to apktool project

Tags: android, android-support-library, decompiler, apktool

I want to add appcompat v7 to a apktool project so i can use Theme.AppCompat.Light. I have added the .smail files for appcompat v7 to the smail folder. But when i add `<style name="style1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` to styles.xml i get

`styles.xml:23: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'`. Is there a way to get this to work?  (or another way to colour the action bar without using targetsdkverion > 18?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: @Antimony No because i cant find on that works with APK tool